# OpenCV complie bug about " cvloadimage" ,referenced from:_main in main.o

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, x86-64

I have a problem.
Here's the error:

> undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
>    " cvloadimage" ,referenced from:_main in main.o

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is named `cvLoadImage()`. Remember: **C** is a case-sensitive programming language.

This function is implemented in **libopencv_highgui.dylib**, you better link your application with it. Make sure your OpenCV libraries are also `x86_64`, else the linking won't work. To check their architecture execute a command-line tool named `file` on them.

You can force the build of your application to be 32bits by specifying `-arch i386 -m 32`, if you are using gcc.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP,I SLOVE MY PROBLEM THAT I SAW  YOUR COMMENT.